# How Can I Use Symbols With a Legend

Tags: d3.js, svg

I've got a legend, with colored rectangles...

[image]

I'd like to replace the rectangles with symbols (i.e., circle, cross, diamond, square). I can't figure out how to do that.

I've been using variations of `.attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type('circle')`. For instance, I tried:

```
        legendRect
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function (d) { return d[2] })
```

and I tried:

```
        legendRect.append("svg:path")
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type((d: any) => { return d[2] }))
```

`d[2]` is "supposed to be" pulling from `legendData`, as shown in the below code example...like it does with `d[1]` for the `fill`.

But I don't ever see anything change.

Here's the code I'm using for the legend, ***without*** the symbol stuff, below. What am I doing wrong and how can I change the rectangles to symbols? Where do I need to add what?

```
        var legendData = [["OA", "yellow", "circle"], ["OI", "blue", "cross"], ["RARC", "green", "diamond"], ["CAPE", "red", "square"], ["Other", "black", "triangleDown"]];

        var legend = this.svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("height", 0)
            .attr("width", 0)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(-20,250)');

        var legendRect = legend.selectAll('rect').data(legendData);

        legendRect.enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", width - 65)
            .attr("width", 10)
            .attr("height", 10)
            ;

        legendRect
            .attr("y", function (d, i) {
                return i * 20;
            })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return d[1];
            })

        var legendText = legend.selectAll('text').data(legendData);

        legendText.enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", width - 52);

        legendText
            .attr("y", function (d, i) {
                return i * 20 + 9;
            })
            .text(function (d) {
                return d[0];
            });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I would code it.  Notice, that I data-bind to a wrapper `g` element and then place the symbol and text into it for each legend item.  You can then  position the `g` instead of positioning the text and "symbol" separately.  This also removes the need for double-binding the data.

```js
var legendData = [["OA", "yellow", "circle"], ["OI", "blue", "cross"], ["RARC", "green", "diamond"], ["CAPE", "red", "square"], ["Other", "black", "triangleDown"]];

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);

var legend = svg.append('g')
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("height", 0)
    .attr("width", 0)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(20,20)');

var legendRect = legend
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(legendData);

var legendRectE = legendRect.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d,i){
      return 'translate(0, ' + (i * 20) + ')';
    });
    
legendRectE
    .append('path')
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type((d) => { return d[2] })) 
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d[1];
    });

legendRectE
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 5)
    .text(function (d) {
        return d[0];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I had originally accepted sparta93's answer, because I saw it before yours; but I just switched to your approach due to the easier positioning of the legend.

Answer (score 2):

This is a implementation which uses symbols for your legend. You can use the symbols like the following:

```
   svg.selectAll('.symbol')
     .data(legendData)
     .enter()
     .append('path')
     .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
       return 'translate(' + (20) + ',' + ((i * 20) + 10) + ')';
     })
     .attr('d', d3.symbol().type(function(d, i) {
         if (d[2] === "circle") {
           return d3.symbolCircle;
         } else if (d[2] === "cross") {
           return d3.symbolCross;
         } else if (d[2] === "diamond") {
           return d3.symbolDiamond;
         } else if (d[2] === "square") {
           return d3.symbolSquare;
         } else {
           return d3.symbolTriangle;
         }
       })
       .size(100))
     .style("fill", function(d) {
       return d[1];
     });
```

Then you can set your legend labels like the following:

```
   svg.selectAll('.label')
     .data(legendData)
     .enter()
     .append('text')
     .attr("x", "40")
     .attr("y", function(d, i){ return ((i * 20)+15);})
     .text(function(d) {
       return d[0];
     });
```

Check fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/zoxckLe3/

P.S. - Above solution uses d3 v4. To achieve the same in v3, use the following line `.attr('d', d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d){return d[2];}))` instead of the part where I match `d[2]` to the symbol name.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is v4 and as such not compatible with OP's code, which uses v3. Interestingly enough, this is the accepted answer although there is no word mentioning the switch of versions.

Comment: Ok, it's officially v4 now ;-) But your advice regarding v3 is  what's used in OP's second snippet, right?

Comment: Thanks @sparta93. I caught the v4 vs v3 difference and adjusted my code accordingly (with exactly what you have since edited) when I first received and accepted your answer. I probably should've come back and mentioned that.

Answer (score -1):

For adding image icons, you can use below code.

```
legend.append("**image**")
        .attr("x", 890)
        .attr("y", 70)
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .attr("xlink:href",function (d) {
            **return "../assets/images/dev/"+d+".png";**
        })
```

This works for me..