# How can I determine the width of a dynamically sized d3 element that is not a text element?

Tags: typescript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to determine the size of a d3 element that is dynamically sized. I've seen examples with `.getBBox()`, like this one -- [D3.js: How to get the computed width and height for an arbitrary element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990857/d3-js-how-to-get-the-computed-width-and-height-for-an-arbitrary-element) -- which says to use `selection.node().getBBox()`. But when I try to use it, I get an error: `[ts] Property 'getBBox' does not exist on type 'Node'.`

I am assuming (maybe incorrectly) that I should replace "selection" with the name of my element? So in my case, I changed `selection.node().getBBox()` to `legend.node().getBBox()`.

I'm thinking the error might be something unique to TypeScript, rather than something I'd see in JavaScript, maybe? (Or maybe not.)

So how can I measure the element's width, using TypeScript?

Here's my code section with the legend, as it currently stands:

```
        var legendData = [["OA", "yellow", "circle"], ["OI", "blue", "cross"], ["RARC", "green", "diamond"], ["CAPE", "red", "square"], ["Other", "black", "triangle-down"]];

        this.svg.selectAll('.legend').remove() //remove remnants of previous legend so new legend has clean slate...eliminates overlays during resizing

        //var svg = d3.select('svg').append('svg').attr('width', 900).attr('height', 500); 

        var legend = this.svg.append('g')
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("height", 0)
            .attr("width", 0)
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width * 0.5 + ',10)'); 

        var legendRect = legend
            .selectAll('g')
            .data(legendData);

        var legendRectE = legendRect.enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                return 'translate(' + ((i * 80) + 0) + ', ' + 10 + ' )';  // y is constant  and x growing symbols
            });

        legendRectE
            .append('path')
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type((d) => {
                return d[2]
            }
            ).size((d3.min([height, width]) * ScatterChart.Config.axisFontMultiplier) * (d3.min([height, width]) * ScatterChart.Config.symbolSizeMultiplier)))
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return d[1];
            })
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            ;

        legendRectE
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("y", 5)
            .text(function (d) {
                return d[0];
            })
            .style('font-size', function () { return d3.min([height, width]) * ScatterChart.Config.axisFontMultiplier + "px" })
            ;
```

Comment: `getBBox()` does not exist on type Node. It is there in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868636.aspx

Comment: This is definitely a TypeScript problem.  It is confused about the types returned from `.node()`. Which version of d3 are you using?  What is the type of "legend"?

Comment: @Mark the legend is the one you helped me with a couple days ago, for a symbols question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42653634/how-can-i-use-symbols-with-a-legend/42655704#42655704. I think the answer to the type is a "g element"?

Comment: `I think the answer to`... find the spot in your code where you declare the `legend` variable and update your question with it.  It's not a `g element`, it should be a `d3` selection if you are calling `.node()` on it.  My guess is you have not typed it properly.

Comment: @Mark. I added the code I'm using to the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you need to re-evaluate why you are using TypeScript.  That code is straight JavaScript and does not take advantage of any TypeScript features.  Are you even loading the [typings definition](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped) for d3?

Comment: @Mark. I'm using TypeScript for a Power BI custom visual. Yes, I have the typings loaded.

Comment: So, what if you provided a type for `legend`:  `let legend : d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, null, any> = this.svg.append('g')...`

Comment: @Mark. This "seems" to be working for me: 
`var node: SVGElement = <SVGElement>legend.node()`

`var legendWidth = node.getBoundingClientRect().width`

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  Did my suggestion also work?  It should give legend a type, so that TypeScript would know that `.node()` returns an `SVGGElement`

Comment: @Mark. When I provided the type as you suggested, I got an error: `[ts] Generic type 'Selection<Datum>' requires 1 type argument (s)`. I think this might be because I'm using d3 v3.5? I think what you proposed works with v4?